# iOS: Twilio Verify for React Native: Exception while calling the API

Tags: ios, react-native, twilio, twilio-api, verify

I'm using [Twilio Verify for React Native](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-verify-for-react-native) and I'm getting an error (log below) when using [their snippet to create a Factor](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-verify-for-react-native#create-factor):

```js
export async function createTwilioVerifyFactor(identity) {
  const pushToken = await messaging().getToken()

  const accessTokenResponse = await getTwilioVerifyAccessToken(identity)
  const hashedIdentity = accessTokenResponse.identity
  const accessToken = accessTokenResponse.token

  try {
    const factor = await TwilioVerify.createFactor(
      new PushFactorPayload(
        // factor name
        Device.deviceName ?? 'Unknown Device',
        Constants.manifest.extra.twilioVerifyServiceSid,
        hashedIdentity,
        pushToken,
        accessToken
      )
    )
    if (!factor.sid) throw new Error('Failed to create factor')
    return factor
  } catch (e) { console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2) }
}
```

I made sure none of the required values are `null`/`undefined`, but I'm still getting an error.

**Android devices give no trouble**, but iOS devices do. The `try / catch` block results in the following log:

```
{
  "nativeStackAndroid": [
    {
      "lineNumber": 95,
      "file": "FactorAPIClient.kt",
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "class": "com.twilio.verify.api.FactorAPIClient$create$2"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 61,
      "file": "FactorAPIClient.kt",
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "class": "com.twilio.verify.api.FactorAPIClient$create$2"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 68,
      "file": "NetworkAdapter.kt",
      "methodName": "execute",
      "class": "com.twilio.verify.networking.NetworkAdapter"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 89,
      "file": "FactorAPIClient.kt",
      "methodName": "create",
      "class": "com.twilio.verify.api.FactorAPIClient"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 49,
      "file": "FactorRepository.kt",
      "methodName": "create",
      "class": "com.twilio.verify.domain.factor.FactorRepository"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 87,
      "file": "PushFactory.kt",
      "methodName": "create",
      "class": "com.twilio.verify.domain.factor.PushFactory"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 55,
      "file": "FactorFacade.kt",
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "class": "com.twilio.verify.domain.factor.FactorFacade$createFactor$1"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 43,
      "file": "FactorFacade.kt",
      "methodName": "invoke",
      "class": "com.twilio.verify.domain.factor.FactorFacade$createFactor$1"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 68,
      "file": "Executor.kt",
      "methodName": "run",
      "class": "com.twilio.verify.threading.Task"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 1167,
      "file": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
      "methodName": "runWorker",
      "class": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 641,
      "file": "ThreadPoolExecutor.java",
      "methodName": "run",
      "class": "java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker"
    },
    {
      "lineNumber": 929,
      "file": "Thread.java",
      "methodName": "run",
      "class": "java.lang.Thread"
    }
  ],
  "userInfo": null,
  "message": "{60401} Exception while calling the API",
  "code": "EUNSPECIFIED",
  "line": 5737,
  "column": 45,
  "sourceURL": "http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=my.app&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true"
}
```

Am I potentially doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer to why this code was not working on iOS.
My mistake was that I was trying to use a FCM token where I should have used an APNs token.
As for Android, the same implementation just worked all of a sudden so I'm updating my question's title.

##### My solution

I created a helper function to get the PNs token depending on the platform using the FCM token as fallback.

```js
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'

export default async function getPushNotificationsToken() {
  if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
    const token = await messaging().getAPNSToken()
    if (token) return token
  }

  return messaging().getToken()
}
```

And I replaced this line in my initial code:

```js
const pushToken = await messaging().getToken()
```

```js
const pushToken = await getPushNotificationsToken()
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I see a couple of potential issues here. First, the error says:

> {60401} Exception while calling the API

[Error 60401](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/errors/60401) implies there was a network error. You say that this was not an issue in an emulator, but happened on real devices. Did you check those real devices' network connections?

Secondly, you're using `const` to declare the `factor` variable inside the `try/catch` block, however you then try to use the `factor` variable after the `catch` block. At that stage the `factor` is now out of scope as `const`s are block scoped. You'll likely get an error like "Cannot read properties of undefined". It's probably best to do the rest of your logic within the `try` bock.

```js
  try {
    const factor = await TwilioVerify.createFactor(
      new PushFactorPayload(
        // factor name
        Device.deviceName ?? 'Unknown Device',
        Constants.manifest.extra.twilioVerifyServiceSid,
        hashedIdentity,
        pushToken,
        accessToken
      )
    )
    if (!factor.sid) throw new Error('Failed to create factor')

    return factor
  } catch (e) { console.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2) }
}
```

Comment: Oops, that `try/catch` block was added last-minute to illustrate the issue.

Comment: It would definitely illustrate _an_ issue ;) . Have you checked for network errors though?

Comment: Wow! Quick answer - Yes, I did check the network connection on the devices and everything but the Twilio API seemed to work fine

Comment: Updated my question, thank you for the feedback :)

Comment: Hmm... OK. I don't have the setup to check this myself right now. It might help you to open this as an issue on [the repo for the React Native module for Twilio Verify](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-verify-for-react-native/issues). That way the team responsible can have a look and make suggestions.